# Numpy: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt 

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

# Load data
company = 'FB'

start = dt.datetime(2012,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)

data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', start, end)

#Prepare Data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_date = scaler.fit_transform(data['Close'].values.reshape(-1,1))

prediction_days = 60

x_train = []
y_train = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_date)):
    x_train.append(scaled_date[x-prediction_days:x, 0])
    y_train.append(scaled_date[x, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train[1], 1)) #the error's here
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/evgenypavlov/Documents/ml_tutorial_1/main.py", line 34, in
>
> x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train[1], 1))   File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in reshape   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py",
> line 299, in reshape
> return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py",
> line 67, in _wrapfunc
> return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py",
> line 44, in _wrapit
> result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds) TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

As far as I know, I am already converting it to np.array, so what can cause this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Did you mean `x_train.shape[1]` on that last line instead of `x_train[1]`?

Comment: You missed a "shape" in the last line: np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

Comment: looks like it, cheers guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `shape` in the second element of the tuple:

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
```